# What's the opposite of withholding taxes?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm building a software for invoices for Mexico and we have the convention to name our variables in English only.

In Mexico there are two types (or categories) of taxes: *Retenciones* and *Traslados*.

`Retenciones` is an easy one: **withholding** taxes. But i can't find a word for the other type of taxes that are not withheld. Is there a word in English I could use before giving up and just use `regularTaxes`?

The main difference is that *Traslados* are taxes **added** to the total amount of the invoice, while *Retenciones* (withholdings) are **subtracted**.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're talking about two entirely different types of "invoices".  "Withholding" is done on earnings -- wages, dividends, or interest, and would be shown on a "payroll statement".  Added taxes would be something like "sales taxes", which are added to the price of something, as shown on a "sales receipt".

Comment: Are your _retenciones_ the so-called ISR (_Impuestos sobre la renta_)? And the regular taxes are IVA?

Comment: Well, yes, but _retenciones_ can contain IVA too, when the invoice is a _recibo de honorario_

Comment: This is a really a technical question where the answer should come from someone familiar with the tax terminology used in Mexico. Context is everything, and a simple English translation of a word would not necessarily  be the right answer. This is not a question about the English language.

Comment: The answer below is fine then, and "withholding" still works in the cases of _recibos de honorario_. "Added", or just VAT works for the second category. [My wife is a CPA working for USAID here in Guate, and those are the same terms they use.

Answer (score 2):

Added would in fact be perfectly fine as it is, for your particular use here I would say.

In the UK there is a tax called VAT (Value Added Tax), see the following Oxford Dictionary [definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vat#VAT_Residual_002).

So there is a precedent for using 'added' in this particular tax context, when you are talking about a tax that is added, versus deducted.

Comment: A VAT tax is the rough equivalent of a "sales tax" in the US.  (The difference is in the way the tax is calculated -- VAT on "added value" at each stage of transfer, sales tax on final retail amount.  But the net effect on the total invoice amount is the same.)

Comment: No; it is 'Value' that 'Added' modifies here, not 'Tax'. This is a wrong argument.